# Create clean text (without \n ) and add the language : HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden Python

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, http-error

I am currently working on som Natural Language Processing in Python. The goal here is to get some pdf into text then do some text cleaning.
As the title is trying to tell I'm trying to do some text cleaning, I use TextBlob and here below is my def:

Additional info previsous to this cell I Used PDFMiner: PDF to Text.

````
def get_language(row):
    b = TextBlob(row['clean_text'])
    return b.detect_language()

df_cvs['clean_text'] = df_cvs['text'].str.replace('\n', ' ')
df_cvs.loc[:, 'language'] = df_cvs.apply(lambda row: get_language(row), axis=1)

df_cvs.head(2)```



Now the error is the following: 


Error details below: **HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden**
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-f02d06c663d3> in <module>
      6 
      7 df_cvs['clean_text'] = df_cvs['text'].str.replace('\n', ' ')
----> 8 df_cvs.loc[:, 'language'] = df_cvs.apply(lambda row: get_language(row), axis=1)
      9 
     10 df_cvs.head(2)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwds)
   7546             kwds=kwds,
   7547         )
-> 7548         return op.get_result()
   7549 
   7550     def applymap(self, func) -> "DataFrame":

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in get_result(self)
    178             return self.apply_raw()
    179 
--> 180         return self.apply_standard()
    181 
    182     def apply_empty_result(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    269 
    270     def apply_standard(self):
--> 271         results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
    272 
    273         # wrap results

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
    298                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
    299                     # ignore SettingWithCopy here in case the user mutates
--> 300                     results[i] = self.f(v)
    301                     if isinstance(results[i], ABCSeries):
    302                         # If we have a view on v, we need to make a copy because

<ipython-input-71-f02d06c663d3> in <lambda>(row)
      6 
      7 df_cvs['clean_text'] = df_cvs['text'].str.replace('\n', ' ')
----> 8 df_cvs.loc[:, 'language'] = df_cvs.apply(lambda row: get_language(row), axis=1)
      9 
     10 df_cvs.head(2)

<ipython-input-71-f02d06c663d3> in get_language(row)
      3 def get_language(row):
      4     b = TextBlob(row['clean_text'])
----> 5     return b.detect_language()
      6 
      7 df_cvs['clean_text'] = df_cvs['text'].str.replace('\n', ' ')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\textblob\blob.py in detect_language(self)
    566         :rtype: str
    567         """
--> 568         return self.translator.detect(self.raw)
    569 
    570     def correct(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\textblob\translate.py in detect(self, source, host, type_)
     70         data = {"q": source}
     71         url = u'{url}&sl=auto&tk={tk}'.format(url=self.url, tk=_calculate_tk(source))
---> 72         response = self._request(url, host=host, type_=type_, data=data)
     73         result, language = json.loads(response)
     74         return language

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\textblob\translate.py in _request(self, url, host, type_, data)
     90         if host or type_:
     91             req.set_proxy(host=host, type=type_)
---> 92         resp = request.urlopen(req)
     93         content = resp.read()
     94         return content.decode('utf-8')

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    220     else:
    221         opener = _opener
--> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    223 
    224 def install_opener(opener):

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    529         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    530             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 531             response = meth(req, response)
    532 
    533         return response

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    638         # request was successfully received, understood, and accepted.
    639         if not (200 <= code < 300):
--> 640             response = self.parent.error(
    641                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    642 

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    567         if http_err:
    568             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 569             return self._call_chain(*args)
    570 
    571 # XXX probably also want an abstract factory that knows when it makes

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    500         for handler in handlers:
    501             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 502             result = func(*args)
    503             if result is not None:
    504                 return result

~\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    650 
    651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
````

Comment: seems like `TextBlob` needs authentication but you haven't provided the credential?

Comment: Thank for your comment :) I had from textblob import TextBlob before the def , Am I missing something?

Comment: i'm not familiar with that lib. but just cloned [src](https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob) from github, and checked [detect_language] (https://github.com/sloria/TextBlob/blob/dev/textblob/blob.py). it uses some google api online. so that's why you see http error. the method is deprecated.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!!  I will take a look at it :)